# How to test that a before_filter works correctly with RSpec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a `check_user_access_control` before_filter in my ApplicationController that checks the logged user's roles and permissions before it lets him through. I am trying to write some tests on it and I can't find a good way of doing it.

For simple index actions I simply do:

```
it "allows access to mod" do
  login_as(Factory(:mod)) # this is a spec helper
  get :index
  response.code.should == "200"
end
```

and it works just fine. For edit/show/create and other actions that need some params, interactions with the database and possible redirect after they run, it needs too many other stuff to be stubbed.

**Is there a way to test if a specific action has been called after the before_filters?** I am looking for something like `controller.should_receive(:action_name)` (which doesn't work) to replace the `response.code.should == "200"` line with.

versions: rails 3.0.4 and rspec 2.5

I tried another approach. We have a method in ApplicationController called `redirect_to_login` that I am now checking for with `controller.should_receive(:redirect_to_login)` and works.

While it detects correctly if the user is allowed or not, it stubs the method, which means that the controller action is run whether or not the user is allowed. Moreover the action depends on params and database and we don't want that.

If now I stub the action method with `controller.stub!(:action_name)`, the action is not run but RSpec is still looking for the template. Well, some actions don't have templates, they just end with a `redirect_to :action => :somewhere_else` or `render :text => "foobar"` which at this point we don't care about.

In sort, what I need now is to find a way to make RSpec **NOT** worry about the template's existence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When stubbing, you could still give a dummy implementation. Inside that implementation you could then raise an error, to make sure all execution is halted, or you do a redirect anyway.

E.g.

```
controller.should_receive(:redirect_to_log) { redirect_to login_url }
```

or

```
controller.should_receive(:redirect_to_log) { raise StandardError.new('login error') }
expect { get :index }.to raise_error
```

For more information check out the awesome [rspec documentation](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The first block did not seem to work but the second one (the one that raises an error) worked like a charm! Now, onwards to find a way to do the opposite: keep the action method from running when we have `controller.should_not_receive(:redirect_to_log)` in the example.

Comment: Normally I would most definitely test the method that you use as `before_filter` standalone: given a user, does it take the correct decision whether or not access is allowed. On your controller you could just test: if a user should not be allowed access, then the `redirect_to_log` should be called (what I shown above). If a user has access, the `redirect_to_log` should not be called, and `response.status.should == 200` (in that case I assume you would not have troubles finding the views, right?). SO just test that it works succesfully.

Comment: I tried this approach but the problem is that some actions (like create) does not end with a 200 but with a 302 (redirects to show). Also some of them need a ton of params and DB access to function (even filesystem access for some of them) that I want to by-pass cause you can only stub so much. **Running the action method itself is what is killing me cause it isn't the purpose of these authorization tests anyway.**

Comment: I THINK FOUND A WAY!!! Will post it as an edit to the question as soon as I'm comfortably sure that it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

To extend [@nathanvda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5884317/282110):

> When stubbing, you could still give a dummy implementation. Inside that implementation [...] do a redirect anyway.

You need to specify `controller` in the block:

```
expect(controller).to receive(:redirect_to_log) { controller.redirect_to login_url }
```

RSpec has a matcher that is also called `redirect_to` that takes precedence when looking up the method. Calling it directly on the controller works around that.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution, with thanks to nathanvda:

```
it "allows access to moderator" do
  login_as(Factory(:mod))
  controller.stub!(action) { raise "HELL" }

  controller.should_not_receive(:redirect_to_login)
  expect { get action }.to raise_error(/HELL/)
end

it "denies access to user" do
  login_as(Factory(:user))

  controller.should_receive(:redirect_to_login) { raise "HELL" }
  expect { get :index }.to raise_error(/HELL/)
end
```

posted on https://gist.github.com/957565